# DataTable losing fnCreatedCell after onClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Here is a fiddle that shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/32602/

If you go to the fiddle you will notice the last column is a link. If you click the checkbox on the first column you lose the link. I would like to keep the link.

I am creating the link in the DataTable like so...

```
{
    data: 'dept',
    "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
      $(nTd).html("<a href='Freight_ITN.aspx?scn=" + oData.dept + "' target='_blank'>" + "ITN ENTRY" + "</a>");
}
```

The `onClick` event of the checkbox is where I am losing my link (I think):

```
$('#mytable tbody').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function (e) {
    var active = $(this).prop('checked');
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    console.log($row);
    var record = oTable.row($row).data();
    record.active = active;
    //console.log(record);
    oTable.row($row).data(record).draw(false);
});
```

I noticed that DataTable has a [`fnDrawCallback`](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/11260/#Comment_11260), however it appears to be deprecated, and I'm unsure how to use it to get my link back.

Comment: I would think you would want to use the column render feature instead of the fnCratedCell.   Also, you might need to invalidate the row before the draw.   I would try oTable.row($row).invalidate().draw(false); instead of oTable.row($row).data(record).draw(false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add the rendering function to the column definitions configuration for your DataTable.

See the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/34ufp3ps/1/

```
columnDefs: [{
  render: function(value, type, record, cellIndex) {
    if (record.active) {
        return value; // If selected, show the value instead of a link.
    } else {
        return '<a href="Freight_ITN.aspx?scn=' + value + '" target="_blank">' + 'ITN ENTRY</a>';
    }
  },
  targets: 4 // Column #4 (Dept)
}]
```

---

## Code

I made your class names Capitalized and added a convenience `insert()` method for proper OOP encapsulation of your Model object.

```js
function Employee(id, firstName, lastName, dept, active, displayAsLink) {
  var self = this;
  this.id = id;
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.dept = dept;
  this.active = active;
  this.displayAsLink = displayAsLink;
}

function EmployeeModel() {
  var self = this;
  this.employees = [];
}
EmployeeModel.prototype.insert = function(employee) {
  this.employees.push(employee);
}

var myModel = new EmployeeModel();

$(document).ready(function() {
  myModel.insert(new Employee('1', 'Clara', 'Dellinger', 'IT', false, true));
  myModel.insert(new Employee('2', 'John', 'Smith', 'HR', false, true));
  myModel.insert(new Employee('3', 'Fred', 'Jones', 'Finance', false, false));
  myModel.insert(new Employee('4', 'Mary', 'Jans', 'Finance', false, false));
  myModel.insert(new Employee('5', 'Bob', 'Jones', 'IT', false, false));
  myModel.insert(new Employee('6', 'Fred', 'Thebes', 'HR', false, true));
  myModel.insert(new Employee('7', 'Sally', 'Jane', 'HR', false, true));
  myModel.insert(new Employee('8', 'Patrick', 'Roberts', 'HR', false, true));
  myModel.insert(new Employee('9', 'Lisa', 'Myers', 'Lab', false, true));
  myModel.insert(new Employee('10', 'Roscoe', 'Coletrain', 'Security', false, true));

  var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
    data: myModel.employees,
    columns: [{
      data: 'active',
      render: function(data, type, row) {
        if (type === 'display') {
          return '<input type="checkbox" class="editor-active">';
        }
        return data;
      },
      className: "dt-body-center"
    }, {
      data: 'id'
    }, {
      data: 'firstName'
    }, {
      data: 'lastName'
    }, {
      data: 'dept'
    }],
    columnDefs: [{
      render: function(value, type, record, cellIndex) {
        if (record.active) {
          return value;
        } else {
          return '<a href="Freight_ITN.aspx?scn=' + value + '" target="_blank">' + 'ITN ENTRY</a>';
        }
      },
      targets: 4 // Column #4 (Dept)
    }],
    rowCallback: function(row, data) {
      // Set the checked state of the checkbox in the table
      $('input.editor-active', row).prop('checked', data.active);
    },
    aaSorting: [
      [3, 'asc']
    ],
  });

  $('#mytable tbody').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e) {
    var active = $(this).prop('checked');
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var employee = table.row($row).data();
    employee.active = active;
    //console.log(employee);
    table.row($row).data(employee).draw(false);
  });

  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
      var isSelected = aData[0];
      var keywords = $("#mysearch").val().toLowerCase().split(' ');
      var matches = 0;
      for (var k = 0; k < keywords.length; k++) {
        var keyword = keywords[k];
        for (var col = 0; col < aData.length; col++) {
          if (aData[col].toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) > -1) {
            matches++;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      return (matches == keywords.length) || (isSelected === 'true')
    }
  );

  $('#mysearch').keyup(function() {
    table.draw();
  });
});
```

```css
.dataTables_filter {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
  <input type="text" id="mysearch" name="mysearch" placeholder="search" />
</div>

<table class="table" id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>First</th>
      <th>Last</th>
      <th>Dept</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks I've been looking at render however is it possible to make a decision using render? for example in the fnCreatedCell I have access to oData so how would I do something like  if (oData.RqrdReview === 'U') { return whatever } else { return something else}

Comment: What does `oData.RqrdReview` mean? Like whether the text shows up as a link or not?

Comment: I just mean I would like to access stuff from my model so in my case it would be oData.id or oData.firstName or oData.lastName etc. I would like to use the data to make decisions about what to render so if the first name is smith then render a link for the department else render a label

Comment: OK, I see. I updated my response. I changed the parameter list to what was displayed when I logged the `arguments` of the render function. Just change your conditional to what suits you and choose what you want to render for the given record.

Answer (score 0):

I just commented:

```
//table.row($row).data(employee).draw(true);
```

It is not necesssary to draw again in order to have the updated data.

```
employee.active = active;//this line updates the data.
```

You can add these two lines to verify:

```
e = table.row($row).data();
console.log(e);
```

The rendering function to the column definitions configuration for your DataTable is also correct.